# Activate Build for Any Mac (Apple Silicon, Intel) in old MacOS app

Tags: xcode, macos, apple-silicon

I want to port my MacApp to a universal build including binaries for the new Apple Silicon Arm64 chips.

Besides being on Xcode 12.1, using the Standard Architectures build setting, what else do I need to do? My scheme only shows Any Mac (Intel)

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely read Apple's official guide on this topic: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/building_a_universal_macos_binary 
The process is very well covered there.

Also, Apple has one more guide for Apple Silicon: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/porting_your_macos_apps_to_apple_silicon 
It's also a must-read.

So the first step is obviously to update the architectures list.
Current MacMini/Macbooks have `x86_64`, Apple Silicon has `arm64` and so on.

The you should compile, and remove all compile errors one by one.

When building my app for Apple Silicon, I've faced such issues:

**Wrap platform-specific code (this headline copied from Apple tutorial :) )**

e.g.

```
#if os(macOS)
   // Put CPU-independent macOS code here.
   #if arch(arm64)
      // Put 64-bit arm64 Mac code here.
   #elseif arch(x86_64)
      // Put 64-bit x86_64 Mac code here.
   #endif
#elseif targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
   // Put Mac Catalyst-specific code here.
#elseif os(iOS)
   // Put iOS-specific code here.
#endif
```

**Build fat libraries (this is a custom explanation :) )**

You app may use any C/C++ static/dynamic libs, such as `Curl`,`OpenSSL` etc.
In order to make an app universal, you should make sure that all these libs contain the code for all platforms.
`lipo` will be you friend here (this is also covered in a guide).
An example of building a static lib for Apple Silicon: https://cutecoder.org/programming/compile-open-ssl-apple-silicon/

I'm not sure I've fully covered your question, so please ask more details and I'll clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 12.1 does not have the macOS 11 SDK, which you need to compile for Apple Silicon. Until macOS 11 ships, you will have to download a beta version of Xcode 12 that includes the macOS 11 SDK, such as the Xcode 12.2 beta.

Comment: "Xcode 12.1 does not have the macOS 11 SDK" - Xcode 12 on MacOS Big Sur does have it :)